# GASでGSSのセルの中身を取得してdiscordに送信したいがエラーになる。

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**やりたいこと**
GASを使用してGSSのセルの中身を取得してdiscordに送信しようと考えています。
初めは
一つのスプレットシートから情報を取得して行おうとしましたが、
二つのスプレットシートから情報を取得しようとしたところ、エラーが発生しました。
どのようにすれば解決できるかわかりません。
アドバイスを頂けると嬉しいです。

```
function submit(){
  discord(get_value())
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx',0);
 

  var datecoord = sheet.getRange(2,3);
  var date = datecoord.getValue();
  //format
  var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(3, 3);
  var format = formatcoord.getValue();

  //配信時間
  var timecoord = sheet.getRange(11,6); 
  var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
  
  var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();


  //a = "お疲れ様です！8/1〜8/15の配信時間は" + haisintime + "時間でした。これからもよろしくお願い致します！(何も無ければ返信は不要です。)"
  
  return message;
  //return value;
};

function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};


function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/yyyy/yyyyyyyyyy',0);
  //webhook
    var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(4,8);
    var webhook = "'"+ webhookcoord.getValue() + "'";

  //token
    var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(4,9);
    var dtoken ="'"+ tokencoord.getValue() + "'";


  //format
    const url        = webhook;
    const token      = dtoken;
    const channel    = '#テスト1';
    const text       = message;
    const username   = '  discord1';
    const parse      = 'full';
    const method     = 'post';

    const payload = {
        'token'      : token,
        'channel'    : channel,
        "content"    : text,
        'username'   : username,
        'parse'      : parse,
    };

    const params = {
        'method' : method,
        'payload' : payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true

    };

   response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

**エラーコード**

```
18:22:59    エラー 
Exception: Invalid argument: 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/878244421785763880/y5ZWFP77u8OwsDzkl2y3TyDhAWNMoNqg8v1pOy5NVNV0P77huluq9oq97rZME-qvbwP4'
discord @ コード.gs:76
submit  @ コード.gs:2
```

Comment: teratailのほうで回答しました。

Comment: 解決しました。　https://teratail.com/questions/358670